# How to change field attribute : readonly and after change button to save

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to modify button.

```
<label>Title</label> <input type="text" name="title" value="${boardVO.title}" readonly="readonly">


<button type="button" onClick="change('asdasd')"
class="btn btn-info">MODIFY</button>
```

and script is

```
function change(target){
  if(target=='asdasd'){
    $("input[name='title']).removeAttr("readOnly");
```

if I first click 'modify', remove readOnly.
and edit text 
one more click 'modify' (second Click) text is saved.

I was thinking about type changing.

If change button type "button" -> "submit", maybe?

if I am correct, then I don't know how to change button type in script

Comment: What is this abomination `javascript_:`  - No need for a label here

Comment: JS is case sensitive. readonly is `readonly` not `readOnly`

Comment: Lastly there is nothing JSP specific here. It is all jQuery related

Comment: `$("input[name='title']").removeAttr("readonly");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You spelled `readonly` as `readOnly` - the attribute is all lowercase
- Just have the button perform some Ajax:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#mod").on("click",function() {
    if (this.innerText=="MODIFY") {
      this.innerText="SAVE";
      $("[name=title]").removeAttr("readonly");
    }
    else {
      this.innerText="MODIFY";
      $("[name=title]").attr("readonly","readonly");
      var title = $.trim($("[name=title]").val());
      if (title) {
        $.post("someurl",{ "title": title },function(data) { console.log(data) });
      }  
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Title</label> <input type="text" name="title" value="${boardVO.title}" readonly="readonly">


<button type="button" id="mod" class="btn btn-info">MODIFY</button>
```

Comment: another ques.
how to call btn in <script>??

Comment: What do you mean? The above just needs to be wrapped in `<script></script>` or live in an external JS file called by  `<script src="externalscript.js"></script>`